# DEFAULT_PATH_LEAF_TO_NULL in jsonPath not working

Tags: java, json, jsonpath, jsonparser, json-path-expression

### JSON

```
{
"abc": {
    "country": [
      {
        "city": "JODHPUR"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

### JSONPath Configuration

```
    private static final Configuration suppressExceptionConfiguration = Configuration
            .defaultConfiguration()
            .addOptions(Option.DEFAULT_PATH_LEAF_TO_NULL)
            .addOptions(Option.SUPPRESS_EXCEPTIONS);
```

### Accessing fields

I am trying to access a field which can exist in some of my sample json and also may not exist.

for e.g.

```
        DocumentContext jsonContext = JsonPath.using(suppressExceptionConfiguration).parse(json);

        String name = jsonContext.read("$.abc.name");
```

### Error

It is giving me error and exiting.

```
com.jayway.jsonpath.PathNotFoundException: No results for path: $['abc']['name']
```

#### Issue

I would like the program to continue and return `null` for this element and this is why I used option like `Option.DEFAULT_PATH_LEAF_TO_NULL` but it is not working.

### My environment

##### Java 17

##### JSONPath version

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Debugging

After debugging jsonPath code using breakpoints in intellij IDE, Realised we need to pass Configuration in each instance of DocumentContext.

For e.g.

##### Configuration

```
    private static final Configuration suppressExceptionConfiguration = Configuration
            .defaultConfiguration()
            .addOptions(Option.DEFAULT_PATH_LEAF_TO_NULL)
            .addOptions(Option.SUPPRESS_EXCEPTIONS);
```

##### Example

Pass above configuration in each instance of DocumentContext to make sure configuration is always applied and not missed.

```
        DocumentContext jsonContext = JsonPath.using(suppressExceptionConfiguration).parse(json);
        DocumentContext name = JsonPath.parse((String) jsonContext.read("$.abc.name"), suppressExceptionConfiguration);
```